# Retrieving an array from within an a JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I've got the following JSON String:

```
{
    "error":false,
    "message":"modules retrieved successfully",
    "subjectsEnrolled":
    {
        "studentNumber":"PT2014-1282",
        "courseId":1,
        "moduleNames":["Internet Programming and E-commerce","Operating Systems","Java and Distributed Systems"]
    }
}
```

and I would like to retrieve the values in `moduleNames`.

Current method to try and retrieve the values is:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    super.onPostExecute(s);

    try {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("moduleNames");

        if (!object.getBoolean("error")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Followed with the following trace:

```
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for moduleNames
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms.ModulesFragment$PerformNetworkRequest.onPostExecute(ModulesFragment.java:166)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms.ModulesFragment$PerformNetworkRequest.onPostExecute(ModulesFragment.java:137)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 20:48:50.741 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-29 20:48:50.746 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
10-29 20:48:50.746 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
10-29 20:48:50.746 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 20:48:50.746 14484-14484/com.example.vhuhwavho.mylms E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for moduleNames
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JsonArray` is in inner `JsonObject` so you have to get an inner object first which is **subjectEnrolled** then you take your array as follows:

```
    JSONObject root_object = new JSONObject(s);
    JSONObject object = root_object.getJSONObject("subjectsEnrolled");
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("moduleNames");
```

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem @Yeezus **Happy Coding!**.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONOBject(s);
    String error = object.getString("error");
    String message = object.getString("message");

    JSONObject obj2 = object.getJSONObject("subjectsEnrolled");
    String studentnumber = obj2.getString("studentNumber");
    String courseid = obj2.getString("courseId");


    JSONArray jarr1 = obj2.getJSONArray("moduleNames");
    Log.d("checkjsonarrayresponsehere==", ""+jarr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out, as mention above,you have to get the inner object first
then will need a step similar to this to read each values in the array.

```
   for(JsonValue value : arrObj){
      System.out.println(value.toString());
   }
```

http://www.java2novice.com/java-json/javax.json/read-json-array/